# Working out a date from a single month number SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, date

Got 2 parameters `@yr` and `@period`, `@period` is just the month number so July would equal 7 for example.

In my stored procedure table I've got a column called `Date` which is just a standard `datetime` field. I need a `where` clause to work out all dates greater than the current period minus 1 year so if `@period = 7 and @yr = 2012` I want the `where` clause to return all dates greater than '01-07-2011' (UK date format) how can I achieve this with just the 2 numbers from `@period` and `@yr`.

```
WHERE <br>
Date >= '01-07-2011'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could

```
Date >= dateadd(month, @period-1, dateadd(year, @yr-1900, 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
where year(date)>year(getdate()-1) and month(date)>@period
```

Comment: This doesnt work as I tried this previously, it doesnt return Jan, feb,mar,april,may or jun for 2012. Returns from July-dec 2011 then only july in 2012.

Comment: how does getdate get into the equation ? Even after replacing getdate() - 1 with yr-1, it will give slow performance and wrong result, never getting january

Answer (score 2):

If you want the expression [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), convert it to datetime:

```
declare @year int = 2012
declare @month int = 7

select 
   ...
where [Date] >= convert(datetime, convert(varchar(4), @year) 
                       + right('0' + convert (varchar(2), @month), 2) 
                       + '01')
```

After seeing Alex K.'s answer, you might even do this:

```
dateadd(month, @month - 1 + (@year-1900) * 12, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the best performance you should do something like this:

```
declare @yr int = 2012
declare @period int = 7

select ...
from ....
WHERE date >= dateadd(month, (@yr - 1901) * 12 + @period - 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just t make sure you compare against an entire date, one solution I'd offer is:

```
Select *
  from TheTable
 where date> DateAdd(Year,-1, convert(datetime, '01/'+convert(varchar,@period)+'/' + convert(varchar,@yr)))
```

To account for regional format differences in SQL Server 2012:

```
Select *
  from TheTable
 where date> DateAdd(Year,-1, DateFromParts(@year,@period,1))
```

For pre-2012:

```
Select *
  from TheTable
 Where Date > DateAdd(day, 0, DateAdd(month, @period-1, DateAdd(year, (@yr-1900)-1,0)))
```

The @yr-1900 is maintained to illustrate the computation of the base date offset from 1900, then subtracting 1 for the one-year-off date computation

Comment: You should include dateformat in your conversion in first answer. Your version 2012 answer is subtracting 2 years. Your pre 2012 is too long. Check my answer or the chosen answer for pre-2012 for the correct syntax

Comment: I added the last two answers to make the result format-neutral. Good catch on the second answer. As far as the third answer goes, to-may-to, to-mah-to. :)

Answer (score 0):

We can do it in may ways

try it

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(20),
        @b VARCHAR(10),
        @c varchar(4)

SET @b='may'  /*pass your stored proc value */
SET @c='2011'

SET @a='01'+@b+@c
SET DATEFORMAT YDM
SELECT CAST(@a AS DATE)

FOR uk formate

SELECT CONVERT(char,CAST(@a AS DATE),103)
```